# Entity Framework make Save method to fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a simple entity and trying to make fail the save method for my unit test.
The question is, how can I make the save method to fail and return false?

```
public class Sampple
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public bool Save()
{
    return (_applicationDbContext.SaveChanges() >= 0);
}
```

Comment: You should use dependency injection and inject applicationDbContext. Maybe you already do that. Then you should create a mock of it that returns something other than 0 on SaveChanges and use the mock in your test. Unfortunately, mocking an EF context is not super easy- but it's doable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here but take care to not waste your time testing EF itself.

Comment: @Yohannis thanks for the advise, if it is to complicate i will only test for pass case.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Yohannis said, dont waste your time testing EF itself.

If you are looking to test what might happen if a `dbcontext.SaveChanges()` failed, whether that be for an incorrectly parsed property or whatever.

try something like this:

```
`try {
   //_applicationDbContext.SaveChanges() 
  throw new Exception();

  // Remember to replace _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges() with 
  //'new Exception' when you are outside of the development db
  return(true); //whilst exception active, here is not hit
}
catch (Exception e) {
  //Error handling here
  return(false);
}`
```

A `try` `catch` will try to complete a process, if it cant, the `catch` will  'catch' the thrown exception. In our case we have purposely thrown a`new Exception` so that we can see exactly what would happen if  `_applicationDbContext.SaveChanges()` did fail. I have included a very basic Exception but there are many types that you can use and tailor to exactly what kind of error you might want to test for.

I have included a link with some relatively simple examples for your consideration.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine